# Should I close the cursor when exiting IntentService?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, android-intentservice

I'm pretty sure the `cursor` is destroyed with the `IntentService` instance, but I just want to be sure there's no memory leak. And if it's a normal practice. I'm querying my custom `ContentProvider`.

```
class MyService extends IntentService {
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            return; // exit the method
        } else {
            cursor.close();
        }
        // some code...
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course yes. Whenever a `Cursor` is used no more, it should be closed immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you work with a cursor, you should wrap it in `try` - `finally` and close it:

```
Cursor cursor = …;
if (cursor == null)
    return;
try {
    …
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

This will ensure no memory leaks will occur even when an exception is thrown.

Java 7 brings try-with-resources but only Android API 19+ supports it:

```
try (Cursor cursor = …)
{
    …
} // Cursor closed automatically
```

Comment: Right, I forgot about exceptions. The `try` block will do the work. Thank you. Wish I could upvote your answer.